# JDBC Version for Weblogic 10 and Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic

we will migrate one application from Oracle 10g to Oracle 11g.

We will not migrate the application Server(WebLogic 10), i would like to know if i need to change the JDBC Version or I can still use the JDBC-Driver  from Oracle 10g.

Best Regards
Edney

Comment: Please, **please** make a proof of concept (or even better, re-run your junit tests regarding JDBC operations) about this, if everything is fine, then keep relaying on the JDBC driver.

Comment: What do the compatibility lists say about the driver you're using? Also, you're not telling which specific jdbc driver you're using, only that it works with Oracle 10g, so it is kind of hard to guess whether it might also work for 11g. If the driver is originally for 10g (or Oracle 9, even), it should work. If the original driver is older than that, I'd start to worry. But as said in the other message, testing will tell a lot.

Comment: Weblogic comes with drivers that are pretty much guaranteed to work with oracle in the wlserver/server/lib directory. Use ojdbc6.jar with java 1.6 etc.